# Error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0

Tags: azure-devops, .net-6.0

I spent 2 hours trying to figure out what's wrong with my pipeline for Azure Functions .NET6 (on Windows).

```
Error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0.  Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0.
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I found the solution here https://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2021/07/azure-devops-building-projects.html 
It works if I specify the .NET Core SDK version & set preview version to true

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '6.0.x'
    includePreviewVersions: true
```

So my final pipelines looks something like this

```
# .NET Core Function App to Windows on Azure
# Build a .NET Core function app and deploy it to Azure as a Windows function App.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master
- main
- dev

variables:
  azureSubscription: 'XXXX'
  functionAppName: 'XXXX'
  vmImageName: 'windows-latest'
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/XXXX'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET 6 Core sdk'
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '6.0.x'
        includePreviewVersions: true

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: |
          $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionApp
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

Comment: The version numbers can be found in this document: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/releases-index.json (for example 6.0.100)

Comment: It seems there's usually a delay between a new version of .NET being released, and these agents supporting that version by default.  At the time of writing, there's an open issue raised for this: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6907

Comment: any idea how that works using classic editor?

Comment: I guess it is Use .NET Core sdk

Comment: I was able to leverage this solution successfully, but did so without `includePreviewVersions: true`.

Comment: Updated the Agent-Specification to windows-2022 and Use .Net Core version to 6 worked for me

Answer (score 16):

For the classic editor - just set the agent to Windows 2022 and make sure to use the latest Nuget Version (I used 5.8 and it worked fine).

Comment: I had set it to Windows Latest which doesn't work. Windows 2022 does.

Comment: This worked for me, i had it on windows 2019 which targeted .net 5.

Answer (score 11):

I had this error when running a project, and installing the .Net 6.0 SDK solved my issue. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.102-windows-x64-installer

Answer (score 4):

A colleague of mine build an console-app towards .net 6.0 in VS 2022.

I opened the solution in VS 2019 and got this exact error.

It worked like a charm when I also used VS 2022..

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I was running pipeline on .Net6 core project made on VS2022. After changing pool `vmimage` to `windows-2022` from `windows-latest`, things worked for me.

[Reference MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops)

Also added latest version for Nugetinstalle
[Nuget versions](https://dist.nuget.org/tools.json)

```
steps:
 - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
 inputs:
   versionSpec: '6.1'
   checkLatest: true
```

Now my pipeline looks like this,

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '6.1'
    checkLatest: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package     /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the error below in latest Visual Studio 2022 17.6 even though I had `SDK 8.0.100-preview.4` installed:

> NETSDK1045    The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.
> Either target .NET 7.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that
> supports .NET 8.0

Looking at release notes they however stated that:

> This release is only compatible with Visual Studio 2022 (v17.7 Preview
> 1).

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-8.0.100-preview.4-windows-x64-installer

Downloaded preview and then it worked.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/#download-preview

Comment: In my case, I had installed VS version 17.7.0 Preview 1.0 along with .NET 8. But after running "dotnet --list-sdks" I could tell that I didn't have any .NET 8 versions installed. Either it's a VS Installer bug or it doesn't install preview versions. So, I had to manually install .NET 8 as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Update Visual Studio to Vs2019 16.11.7 My Problem solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Due to Microsoft breaking changes, an upgrade to Visual Studio can fix this issue;  Is what he was referring to I believe:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/vs-msbuild-version

Comment: Question clearly states it's about Azure

Comment: Updating also solved it with VS 2022.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved** : with **.Net6** core project made on VS2022.Need to use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0.

before .NET Core publish task need to add another Task (**below one for use specific version of SDK 6.0**)

```html
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 6.0.x'
  inputs:
    packageType: '$(Parameters.packageType)'
    version: 6.0.x
    includePreviewVersions: true
```

My complete YAML looks like ( build successfully 26 may, 2022)

```html
variables:
- name: BuildParameters.packageType
  value: sdk
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/Develop
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-2019
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    displayName: 'Use NuGet '
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: NuGet restore
    inputs:
      solution: Marielinas
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: Use .NET Core sdk 6.0.x
    inputs:
      packageType: $(BuildParameters.packageType)
      version: 6.0.x
      includePreviewVersions: true
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet publish
    inputs:
      command: publish
      arguments: -c release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      workingDirectory: Marielinas.ASP.NET6.0
  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: marielinasshop'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 37f84ce6-e4f1-4a03-b107-9c9a527dff4a
      appType: webApp
      appName: marielinasshop
      deployToSlotOrASE: true
      resourceGroupName: GreenLab
      package: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip
...
```